# Missing steps to simplify this complex impedance

Tags: resistors

The problem is: 
[complex imped http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/673/tgoToD.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/673/tgoToD.png)

How would you you simplify the equation to get down to \$716.97 - j450.47\Omega\$? I tried  multiplying by the conjugate but that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm getting \$716.97 + j450.47\Omega\$ by multiplying the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator. I think the imaginary part should be positive since the numerator has a \$j^2 = -1\$ term when multiplying by the complex conjugate.

Comment: [Mathomatic](http://www.mathomatic.org/) tells me: `( 1000 * 1591.6 * i) / ( 1000 + 1591.6 * i ) = (450.47103261818*i) + 716.96969551509`. Notice the `+` sign.

Comment: I did multiple the equation with the denominator conjugate, but I got a different answer. Could you show me your work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clearly a mistake by your textbook, as mentioned in the comments.

$$\frac{1000\cdot j1591.6}{1000+j1591.6}=\frac{1000\cdot j1591.6}{1000+j1591.6}\cdot\frac{1000-j1591.6}{1000-j1591.6}=\frac{10^6\cdot (j1591.6-j^2 2533.19056)}{10^6\cdot(1+j1.5916-j1.5916-j^2 2.53319056)}|_{j^2=(-1)}=\frac{j1591.6+2533.19056}{3.53319056}=\frac{2533.19056}{3.53319056}+j\frac{1591.6}{3.53319056}\approx716.97+j450.47$$

So, multyplying by the complex conjugate of the denominator works to get the result provided by both @Null and @jippie.